# Create dictionary from 3 lists - python

Tags: python, dictionary

Looking for some help in creating a dictionary using 3 python lists

```
a = ['alpha','bravo','charlie']
b = ['a','b','c']
c = [1,2,3]

output:
{'alpha': {'letter': 'a', 'number': 1},
 'bravo': {'letter': 'b', 'number': 2},
 'charlie': {'letter': 'c', 'number': 3}}
```

I tried something like this. This may be close, but needs some tweaking:

```
{k: dict(v) for k,v in zip(a, zip(('letter', b),('number', c)))}
```

Comment: I think you are overthinking this, trying to make it too general. Given `('alpha', 'a', 1)`, how would you create `{'alpha': {'letter': 'a', 'number': 1}}`? The key point in the first two answers is that instead of trying to prepare data for `dict(v)` ahead of time, it's easier to put that complexity into the first clause of the comprehension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `dict` comprehension can `zip` all three iterables at once, and just include a `dict` literal for the sub-`dict`:

```
{k: {'letter': let, 'number': num} for k, let, num in zip(a, b, c)}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should zip all 3 lists together:

```
result = {greek: {'letter': letter, 'number': number} for greek, letter, number in zip(a, b, c)}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `zip`-heavy version (as you seem to have tried that):

```
output = {k: dict(zip(('letter', 'number'), vs))
          for k, vs in zip(a, zip(b, c))}
```

Or:

```
output = {k: dict(zip(('letter', 'number'), vs))
          for k, *vs in zip(a, b, c)}
```

Or to use your `{k: dict(v) for k,v in zip(a, ...)}` and only fix the `...` part:

```
output = {k: dict(v) for k,v in zip(a, map(zip, repeat(('letter', 'number')), zip(b, c)))}
```

Or with some itertools, making C code do all the work (other than configuring the work):

```
from itertools import repeat

output = dict(zip(a, map(dict, map(zip, repeat(('letter', 'number')), zip(b, c)))))
```